# can compile c++ in eclipse - Cannot run program "autoreconf": Launching failed

Tags: eclipse, compiler-construction, eclipse-cdt

I installed eclipse Helios a week ago. First I installed it without the CDT.
Today I installed the CDT along with the autotool (this it what can be seen in the list of possible updates). Afterwards, I installed also the minGW (Wascana) as written in the manual of CDT.
but after I create an Hello World project in eclipse I get this error (blinking non stopable) in the console tab:

Invoking autoreconf in build directory: D:/eclipse/proj/workspace/testcpp

Configuration failed with error
(Cannot run program "autoreconf": Launching failed)

Can anyone help me with this? What else do I need to install or config so my CDT will work?

thanks,
Eli

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the autotools add-in.  I think that's for a specific build system so it may be messing up Eclipse if you don't have those tools already on your system.

Answer (score 1):

The autotools plug-in doesn't work on Windows yet. There is a fix in place for the upcoming Indigo Eclipse release.

The main problem is that Windows doesn't know how to run shell scripts (which is what autoreconf is). You have to launch the shell manually and ask it to run it. And that's what the fix is.

Comment: ok, thank!
now i have the same message just with "make"...

do you know anything about